# Firebase - Cloud Function - "Error: Cloud function needs to be called with an event parameter."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function for creating an user profile when a new user user is created(gosh a lot of "create).

I implemented this function:

```
exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user()
  .onCreate( (userRecord, context) => {
  return admin.database().ref(`/userProfile/${userRecord.data.uid}`).set({
    email: userRecord.data.email
  });
});
```

but when I create a new user, I got this error:

```
Error: Cloud function needs to be called with an event parameter.If you are writing unit tests, please use the Node module firebase-functions-fake.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:84:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /worker/worker.js:731:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

is anyone facing something like that?
any solution so far?

Kind Regards

Comment: According to the current [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) there is no `context` parameter. But I don't see how that would cause this error. :-/

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs the onCreate takes only an event as the parameter and there's no need for context (in this case userRecord): https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

You should then be able to simply access the uid via `userRecord.uid` :)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the latest firebase-functions, which solved the problem on my system. Run

```
npm outdated
```

to see if your firebase-functions is really up to date. NPM by itself won't update past semvers.

My guess is that firebase-functions defines an event class, and it is their internals which pass this event object to the user-defined callback. So if you are using an older version of firebase-functions, the callback is not receiving an "event parameter"

Don't have enough points to comment on Alchemist Shahed's answer, but the docs actually seem to be a bit conflicting on how to call onCreate().

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation
says:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = 
  functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

But the upgrade guide
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#authentication
shows

```
exports.authAction = 
  functions.auth.user().onCreate((userRecord, context) => {
    const creationTime = userRecord.metadata.creationTime; // 
       // 2016-12-15T19:37:37.059Z
    const lastSignInTime = userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime; 
       // 2018-01-03T16:23:12.051Z
}
```

and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder#on-create

also shows the `(user: UserRecord, context: EventContext): PromiseLike<any> | any` handler

So it is not clear if the `context` argument is needed or not.